# I am working on django project when i run >> python manage.py sqlmigrate travello 0001 command it show the following error help on this

Tags: python, reactjs, django

Here is the stack trace I see:

[image: error log]

```
python manage makemigrations
python manage.py sqlmigrate travello 0001
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Your stacktrace screenshot cuts off the last line of the output. Please edit your question to include your full stacktrace as text, rather than as an image.

Comment: As @ShaneBishop said, do that, and which DB are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your database is not yet configured. You should install psycopg2 for that and make sure it's installed in the virtual environment, not globally. Then in settings.py, your database settings must be correct.